# How to convert string to time?

Tags: javascript, parsing, datetime, momentjs

Currently, I'm parsing a JSON which returns a string like this for time "201610161000"(2016-10-16 10:00). I used Momentjs to parse it like this "moment("201610161000", 'YYYYMMDDHHmm')" The problem is that it takes too much time when I parse it with large data. If I remove it, then it only takes 10ms. Otherwise, it takes 1000 ms with Momentjs. Is there a way that I can convert the string above to time without using Moment? (I have no control to change the time format in JSON)

```
var inner = _.map(num.series, function(n, k) {
          return {
            x: moment(n.bucket, 'YYYYMMDDHHmm'),
            y: n,
          };
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using concatenation and split methods in java-script.
Try following approach

```
var jsonTime = "201610161000".split("");
var parsedDate = jsonTime.slice(0, 4).join("") + "-" + jsonTime.slice(4, 6).join("")+ "-" + jsonTime.slice(6, 8).join("")+ "-" + jsonTime.slice(8, 10).join("")+ ":" + jsonTime.slice(10, 12).join("");
//output : 2016-10-16-10:00
```

Comment: Thanks, I decided to use substring instead which reduce the parse time to 100-160ms. I wonder if there are even better approach?

Comment: yes, thats also is a good option than moment. why load an additional library when it can be done using builtin methods. :)